# Chrome 34 SVG Bug

Tags: image, svg, d3.js

I have a d3.js application that renders images as nodes in a connected graph.  After Chrome was updated to 34.0.1847.131, modifying opacity style attribute on an image causes display weirdness.  Images and other svg elements will disappear or become partial rendered.  I have tested in Chrome 33.0.1750.117, as well as recent Firefox and IE versions and they each work as expected.

I created a plunker to demostrate this: http://plnkr.co/1jKDh5JMiuxouQyqZzGy.

If anyone can give me a workaround or if there is something incorrect in my plunker, please let me know.  Otherwise, it appears to be a bug with Chrome 34.  I have reported an issue on Google Chrome forums, and there is another post on the Google Chrome forums with a similar issue.

My Chrome forums post:
http://bit.ly/1lXTHs0

Another user's Chrome forum post:
http://bit.ly/1ilYMsZ

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You should probably report it: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Might be http://crbug.com/363736 or http://crbug.com/363748 (both serious regressions in Chrome 34).

Comment: Erik, agreed.  Chrome 35 beta looks to fix.  I have put in a workaround for Chrome 34 to set display none instead of fading opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary workaround:

The problem with one element's opacity affecting others seems to only apply to sibling elements.  So one solution is to wrap each element inside its own `<g>` element (but still apply the changes in opacity to the element itself).

This SVG code displays fine:

```
<svg>
<g transform="translate(50,30)">
    <g>
        <image class="node" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/GInbcOj.png" x="100" y="50" width="50px" height="50px" style="opacity: 0.30000000000000004;"></image>
    </g>
    <g>
        <image class="node" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/GInbcOj.png" x="300" y="50" width="50px" height="50px" style="opacity: 0.30000000000000004;"></image>
    </g>
    <g>
        <image class="node" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/GInbcOj.png" x="200" y="50" width="50px" height="50px"></image>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect class="node" x="100" y="150" width="50" height="50" style="opacity: 0.30000000000000004;"></rect>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect class="node" x="300" y="150" width="50" height="50" style="opacity: 0.30000000000000004;"></rect>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect class="node" x="200" y="150" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

[Live example with comparison against the SVG from your original code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qazFv/)

For your simple d3 code example, this only requires some extra `append` calls:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("image.node").data(nodeData);

nodes.enter().append("g").append("image")
    .attr("class", "node")
    /* ...*/

svg.selectAll("image.node")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.id <= 2;
  }).transition().delay(1000).style("opacity","0.3");


var rects = svg.selectAll("rect.node").data(nodeData);

rects.enter().append("g").append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    /* ...*/

svg.selectAll("rect.node")
  .filter(function(d) {
    return d.id <= 2;
  }).transition().style("opacity","0.3");
```

However, note that the entering elements added to your selection are now the `<g>` elements, not the shapes, so you need to re-select them before you can modify the shapes themselves.  Your example code already did this, but not all examples would.

It's not ideal — beyond the extra code, you're doubling the number of DOM elements, which could slow things down if you have a lot of elements to start — but it's fairly straightforward to implement now and then remove later once most Chrome users have updated to the patched version.

Comment: That is a nicer workaround that what I was doing with display:none, and easy to implement with d3.js.  Thanks.